VisualSVN Server: force all SVN repositories to be synced with master (not only one of them)
I'm using a master and a slave VisualSVNServer and I configure vdfs to keep them in sync.
However sometime I need to force slave to sync it with master.
In order to force slave-server to be synced with master I'm using below command which is working for just one repository at a time:
Sync-SvnRepository MyRepo1 -PassThru
I'v found this command in VisualSVN Server PowerShell Cmdlet Reference list.
In order to make all repositories be synced, I'm trying to use Get-SvnRepository command to get list of all repositories in slave server and sync them with master server. But I don't know how to pass output of Get-SvnRepository command to Sync-SvnRepository MyRepo1 -PassThru command to make it iterate for all repositories.
